# How to check the correct current time if user sets "Set Automatically" off

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios7

I have to check the correct current time if user sets "Set Automatically" off.

Is there any way to access the status of "Set Automatically" setting status so that I cam prompt user to turn it on.
OR
Another approach I can follow I can fetch the time from GPS(location) but the below code always gives the local time in case of user selects
"Set Automatically" off.

```
CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees) 0.0 longitude:(CLLocationDegrees) 0.0];
NSDate* now = location.timestamp;
```

Is there any way to archive this behavior in ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't rely on the local clock, you need to use an external source.  There are (probably) several NTP-based libraries for this.  For example: ios-ntp, which can currently be found [here](https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp).